# How to build and test an iOS Swift Package officially?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I have a iOS Swift Package (no Objective-C, just Swift) that does not have .xcodeproj or .xcworkspace and would like to run unit test on this. Running a simple `swift test` does not work due to error in third party dependencies. Running [different variations of `xcodebuild`](https://forums.swift.org/t/swiftpm-and-library-unit-testing/26255/20) did not work because of my unit test requiring a @testable import and errors out saying "module 'MyFramework' was not compiled for testing". So I tried using `swift package generate-xcodeproj` thinking I might be able to automatically create xcodeproj and do something clever, but gave me warning "'generate-xcodeproj' is no longer needed and will be deprecated soon.". Obviously I don't want to start using something that is going to be deprecated soon.
[This official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/building_swift_packages_or_apps_that_use_them_in_continuous_integration_workflows) doesn't have any example.

Is there an official way to run and test a pure iOS Swift Package?

Update:

I created a sample SP to replicate this problem [here](https://github.com/gomfucius/ios-swift-package-test).

When I try `swift build`, I get error:

`✗ swift test error: artifact 'FloatingPanel' does not support the target platform and architecture ('Triple(tripleString: "x86_64-apple-macosx", arch: TSCUtility.Triple.Arch.x86_64, vendor: TSCUtility.Triple.Vendor.apple, os: TSCUtility.Triple.OS.macOS, abi: TSCUtility.Triple.ABI.unknown)')`

When I try:

```
xcodebuild \
    -scheme MyLibrary \          
    -configuration Test \
    -derivedDataPath derivedData \
    -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 12 Pro,OS=14.5" \
    -sdk iphonesimulator \
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES \
    -enableCodeCoverage YES \
    -resultBundleVersion 3 \
    VALID_ARCHS=x86_64 \
    -scmProvider system \
    -disableAutomaticPackageResolution \
    test | xcpretty -c
```

I get error:

`MyLibraryTests.swift:2:22: module 'MyLibrary' was not compiled for testing`

I am using Xcode 12.5.

Comment: Any chance you could post enough details - even minimal - to duplicate your issue? I get what didn't work, but even a minimal project might help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, I've updated the question. @dfd

Answer (score 2):

I was able to run the unit test successfully by passing in -xcconfig with a file `ENABLE_TESTABILITY = true` in Config.xcconfig I created. This fixed the issue of `module 'MyLibrary' was not compiled for testing`.

```
xcodebuild \
    -scheme MyLibrary \
    -configuration Test \
    -derivedDataPath derivedData \
    -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 12 Pro,OS=14.5" \
    -sdk iphonesimulator \
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES \
    -enableCodeCoverage YES \
    -resultBundleVersion 3 \
    VALID_ARCHS=x86_64 \
    -scmProvider system \
    -disableAutomaticPackageResolution \
    -xcconfig Config.xcconfig \
    test | xcpretty -c
```

In the Config.xcconfig:

`ENABLE_TESTABILITY = true`

The only other issue is sometimes it fails to find the `MyLibrary` as a scheme.